# how to get variable stored in another object using objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, object

SaveNotes *saveNotes = [[SaveNotes alloc]initWithTitleString:title descrString:descr];
    [titleDescrObjects addObject:saveNotes];
    [saveNotes release];

from the above code i have saved title,descr to a class SaveNotes , and then i have stored that object in my NSMutableArray -> titleDescrObjects,
Its working fine,

i need to get particular objects "descr" alone,

how to get the descr from objectAtIndex:i

i am trying

```
for (int i=0; i<[titleDescrObjects count]; i++)
{   
  NSLog(@"\n ((%@))\n",[titleDescrObjects objectAtIndex:i].descr); 
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-objectAtIndex:` returns an `id`. Since an `id` can be of any Objective-C class, the compiler cannot associate the property `.descr` into a getter, which is why it chooses not to make it valid at all.

There are 3 ways to fix it.

1. Use a getter: `[[titleDescrObjects objectAtIndex:i] descr]`
2. Cast into a SaveNotes: `((SaveNotes*)[titleDescrObjects objectAtIndex:i]).descr`
3. Use fast enumeration. This is the recommended method.

   ```
   for (SaveNotes* notes in titleDescrObjects) {
      NSLog(@"\n ((%@))\n", notes.descr); 
   }
   ```

Comment: excellent Kenny , its worked for case 2,3 , thank you very much.

but its not working for case 1.

Comment: @mac: Maybe your getter of the property `.descr` isn't `-descr`.